# strange appengine query result

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

What am I doing wrong in this query?

```
SELECT * FROM TreatmentPlanDetails 
WHERE 
   accountId = 'ag5zfmRvbW9kZW50d2ViMnIRCxIIQWNjb3VudHMYtcjdAQw' AND 
   status = 'done' AND 
   category = 'chirurgia orale' AND
   setDoneCalendarEventStartTimestamp >= [timestamp for 6 june 2012]  AND 
   setDoneCalendarEventStartTimestamp <= [timestamp for 11 june 2012]  AND 
   deleteStatus = 'notDeleted' 
ORDER BY setDoneCalendarEventStartTimestamp ASC
```

I am not getting any record and I am sure there are records meeting the where clause conditions. To get the correct records I have to widen the timestamp interval by 1 millisecond. Is it normal? Furthermore, if I modify this query by removing the category filter, I am getting the correct results. This is definitely weird.
I also asked on google groups, but I got no answer. Anyway, for details:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/google-appengine/query/google-appengine/ixPIvmhCS3g/d4OP91yTkrEJ

Comment: category = 'chirurgia orale' => category = 'chirurgia orale' AND
I assume this is merely typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's talk specifically about creating timestamps to go into the query.  What code are you using to create the timestamp record?  Apparently that's important, because fuzzing with it a little bit affects the query.  It may be relevant that in the datastore, timestamps are recorded as integers representing posix timestamps with microseconds, i.e. the number of microseconds since 1/1/1970 UTC (not counting leap seconds).  It's also relevant that *dates* (i.e. without a time) are represented as midnight, i.e. the earliest time on that day.  But please show us the exact code.  (It may also be important to show the actual content of the record that you're attempting to retrieve.)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. To avoid such problems, I always store dates as long values (milliseconds since 1/1/1970 UTC). Here is the query: `SELECT * 
FROM TreatmentPlanDetails 
WHERE accountId = 'ag5zfmRvbW9kZW50d2ViMnIRCxIIQWNjb3VudHMYtcjdAQw' AND 
status = 'done'  AND 
category = 'chirurgia orale' AND 
setDoneCalendarEventStartTimestamp >=1338933600000 AND 
setDoneCalendarEventStartTimestamp <= 1339365600000 AND 
deleteStatus = 'notDeleted' 
ORDER BY setDoneCalendarEventStartTimestamp ASC`

Comment: Here is the first record that the query does not return. For simplicity I will report only the properties involved in the query: `accountId='ag5zfmRvbW9kZW50d2ViMnIRCxIIQWNjb3VudHMYtcjdAQw'; status='done'; category='chirurgia orale'; setDoneCalendarEventStartTimestamp=1338933600000; deleteStatus='notDeleted'`

Comment: And here is the second record. Here is the firs record that the query does not return. For simplicity I will report only the properties involved in the query: 
`accountId='ag5zfmRvbW9kZW50d2ViMnIRCxIIQWNjb3VudHMYtcjdAQw'; 
category='chirurgia orale'
status='done'; 
setDoneCalendarEventStartTimestamp=1338933600000; 
deleteStatus='notDeleted'`

Comment: So, for datastore's sake, a timestamp is simply a long property. Simply issuing the above sql in the datastore viewer I get wrong results, so I am sure that there is not a problem of timezone, timestamp generation or else. Is simply a matter of issuing a query which has two filters on a long property. Thanks again.

Comment: @Nicanor: the Python datetime type is an exact type and is stored in the datastore as microseconds since 1/1/1970 UTC. So there's no real advantage to rolling your own here. What you're seeing is more likely due to time.time() returning a float.

Comment: I am using java's java.util.Date.getTime() which returns a long value (milliseconds since epoch). The whole app is written in java. From my point of view, it fails to run certain queries with inequality filters on long properties.

Answer (score 1):

An aside that is not specific to your question: Entity property names count as part of your storage quota. If this is going to be a huge dataset, you might pay more $$ than you'd like for property names like setDoneCalendarEventStartTimestamp.

Comment: Man, you rule so much. You're so right. I never thought of that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Because you write :

> if I modify this query by removing the category filter, I am getting
>   the correct results

this probably means that the category was not indexed at the time you write the matching records to the data store. You have to re-write your records to the data store if you want them added to the newly created index.

Comment: If by rewrite you mean to simply update the records, I already did that. And besides, it doesn't explain why by widening the timestamp interval by 2 milliseconds, the records start matching, while in the query version without the category filter, it matches without widening the interval...